# Revealing Module Pattern variations

Tags: javascript

I've made some researches on the web about the Revealing module pattern, but it seems there are different variations, and I'm a bit confused. What are the main advantages and drawbacks of each of the following variations ?

**Variation 1 :**

```
function Dog(){
    var woof = function () { console.log('woof'); }
    return {woof};
}
var foo = Dog();
```

**Variation 2 :**

```
function Dog(){
    var woof = function () { console.log('woof'); }
    return Object.create({woof});
}
var foo = Dog();
```

**Variation 3 :**

```
function Dog(){
    var woof = function () { console.log('woof'); }
    return Object.freeze({woof});
}
var foo = Dog();
```

Comment: Well variation 2 to me seems a bit pointless, as it's creating a new instance of woof each time anyway.   Variation 3, just protects the function woof from been changed.

Comment: I'd call none of these a *module* pattern, as that implies a single instance. You've written factory functions.

Comment: Where have you seen variation 2? `Object.create` makes no sense whatsover here.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not able to remember the website where I found it. Might be a bad source then.